# Sending parameters to an inverter

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am looking into the possibility if we are able to send commands from a program through an rs232 connection to an inverter. (This inverter [ http://www.bonfiglioli.com/en/industrial/products/inverters-energy-recovery/frequency-inverters/product/active-cube-frequency-inverter/ ]  drives a servo motor).

Currently I have to input all the parameters in a software application, upload those parameters to the machine and then press a button on the machine to run the sequence of events.

A screenshot of the software can be found here:

[cant post images yet, here is a link: http://s4.postimg.org/86xbznvr1/screenie_Vplus.jpg ]

In here, I need to be able to edit the values in columns 'index 1' and 'index 2'. Currently I can enter these value and when I press enter it sends those values directly to the machine.

1: Is there a way (preferably in C#) where I can bypass the software application and send the data directly through the rs232 cable? And if that is not possible;

2: Is there a way that I can write a program who sends those value to the software application and then have the application send those values to the machine?

I am still new to programming, hence these questions. I understand I cannot ask for pieces of code or whatnot but if anyone could point me to a tutorial or the right direction that would help a lot!

TIA.

Comment: With `C#` you can: open com-port, send/receive data, data can be serialized, deserialized, processed, etc. However, your question (1) has to be asked to manufacturer. Sometimes there is no *direct* interface (software used as a bridge interfacing hidden from you complicated internal protocol), sometimes they want you to buy software, etc. If there is a protocol and you get it - answer is yes. For question (2) again, look what this software can first. You can send mouse-clicks, keypresses, etc to open (probably) created by you file and click "Run" button.

Comment: (1): alright, I will look into that, thanks
(2): Is this a macro you are referring to ? The endgame of this question is to have a simulation program (a trainsimulator) send commands so a chair will shake.